# Unwanted powershell output trimming

Tags: powershell, cmd

Trying to read and parse DNS cache in batch file, but in output of command

`powershell Get-DnsClientCache`

is trimmed to fit in screen. So trying to avoid trimming by Out-String -999

`powershell "Get-DnsClientCache | out-string -width 999"`

but this prevent only some columns from trimming, but not all of them. How could I print all columns in its full width to be parsed by batch script?

Comment: Objects are not meant to be parsed nor treated as mere strings. If you're attempting to do this then you have a misconception and should approach the problem differently

Comment: PowerShell will only allow 5 columns as the default when sending to the screen. If you have more than that, it defaults to a list.  There are several formatting options, see them here: ```Get-Command -Name 'format*'```, by viewing the help file detail/examples. Yet,  ditto to what @SantiagoSquarzon said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Opening the Cmd Window MAXIMIZED and adding `Format-Table -Autosize` ?

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get-DnsClientCache
@REM OPEN CMD WINDOW MAXIMIZED
IF NOT "%1"=="MAX" START /MAX CMD /D /C "%~0" MAX & GOTO :EOF 
Powershell -C "Get-DnsClientCache | Format-Table -AutoSize | out-string -width 999"
Pause
```